# Google Analytics doesnt register events when redirected in a second page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Im using Google Analytics 4 and Google Tag Manager to register my events in my Wordpress site.

I have successfully added  Google Tag Manager in both Header and Body and added an simple event called all_clicks and i have submitted all my latest changes.

[image]

The problem is that for some reason i get only events coming from the Home page of my site. If i click somewhere else and redirected, events wont show up in the Realtime report.

In the developers tools the events are being collected as intended for all pages meaning that the GTM is installed.

[image]

and events are also firing in Google Tag Assistant.

Note: If i go to the page that im redirected to by inserted the link directly to the nav bar of the browser, the all_click event will be reported in the Realtime reports. If i do a redirection afterwards, the all_click event wont be reported, even tho it is fired and collected.

Any ideas?